# Image from getImage.php won't display in img src

Tags: php, mysql

So basically if I go to the `getImage` link, the image that comes from the database is displayed, but if I use it in a `.php` file where it will display the image but will resize it to fit the card, it won't show and the alt (which is avatar) shows.

```
<center>
<img src="getImage.php" class="w3-circle" style="position:absolute; bottom:-20%; left:35.5%; width:30%" alt="Avatar">
</center>
```

Then the code for the `getImage.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
require './Database.php';

// do some validation here to ensure id is safe

$sql = "SELECT register.FULLNAME, register.IMAGE, gameData.NBA_SCORE FROM register inner join gameData on register.ID = gameData.ID WHERE NBA_SCORE = (select max(NEW_SCORE) from gameData)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<img src='".$row['IMAGE']."'>";
?>
```

Anything wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Why are you storing images in the database? _Files_ should be stored on the _filesystem_... anyway you are repeating your `img` tag

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this is a website where people can register and upload there image, and the image they uploaded is then stored to the database and is called if they are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

HTML trys to get an valid image file like jpg or png but gets an php/text file with the content `<img src="...">`.

**Solution**

You need to change the php files content type to an image and output the image files data:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");//or image/png
echo file_get_contents("$imagepath");//file path not url!!!
```

**Code**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require './Database.php';

  header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");    

  // do some validation here to ensure id is safe

  $sql = "SELECT register.FULLNAME, register.IMAGE, gameData.NBA_SCORE FROM register inner join gameData on register.ID = gameData.ID WHERE NBA_SCORE = (select max(NEW_SCORE) from gameData)";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $path = $row['IMAGE'];//Maybe you need to change this if you only save an url in the database  
  echo file_get_contents($path);  

?>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! From analyzing this I think the header definitely helped, and Im now going to study the $path. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yeah you should save the files data in a file on the system and save the path in the database. Then you can use the code above with no changes.